# Problema Cadena de caracteres borrar espacios que sobran c++

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa donde se inserta un texto y se debe corregir el mismo eliminando los espacios de más.

Mi problema llega cuando tengo mas de 2 espacios seguidos, sólo elimina la mitad de los espacios totales. Ej: en caso de que escriba `a    b` (en total hay 4 espacios) el programa solo borra 2.

Código:

```
char frase[100];

cout<<"Ingrese frase: "; cin.getline(frase,100);

cout<<frase;

for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    if(frase[i]==' ' and frase[i+1]==' '){
        for(int j=i; j<100;j++){
            frase[j]=frase[j+1];
        }
    }
}

cout<<"\n"<<frase;
```

Y perdón si no es muy entendible, es la primera vez que publico en la página.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si partimos de un caso de ejemplo tal que:

```
h o l a _ _ _ a _ t o d o s
        ^
```

El problema es que incrementas `i` incondicionalmente, es decir, siempre. Cuando eliminas un espacio desplazas los caracteres una posición a la izquierda:

```
h o l a _ _ a _ t o d o s
        ^
        borramos el espacio inicial


h o l a _ _ a _ t o d o s
          ^
          incrementamos i
```

Como ves, ya no somos capaces de detectar los dos espacios consecutivos.

Solo deberías incrementar `i` cuando no eliminas un espacio:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;){
    if(frase[i]==' ' and frase[i+1]==' '){
        for(int j=i; j<100;j++){
            frase[j]=frase[j+1];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Otra posibilidad es recorrer el array a la inversa. Así sí podrías hacer el incremento incondicional:

```
for(int i=strlen(frase)-1;i>=0;i--){ 
    if(frase[i]==' ' and frase[i+1]==' '){
        for(int j=i; j<100;j++){
            frase[j]=frase[j+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Otro error lo tienes en el segundo bucle. Fíjate que iteras en el rango `(i, 99)` y que, por otro lado, accedes a las posiciones `j` y `j+1`.

Esto quiere decir que para `j=99` accedes a la posición 100 del array, y esa posición no pertenece al array (sus posiciones van de 0 a 99). Deberías reducir el rango de iteración para evitar este problema:

```
for(int j=i; j<99;j++){
    frase[j]=frase[j+1];
}
```

Comment: Me sirvió muchísimo, te agradezco.

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo resolvería de la siguiente forma:

```
char frase[100];

cout<<"Ingrese frase: "; cin.getline(frase,100);

cout<<frase;

int n=0;
// Contemplamos el caso que la frase contenga espacios
// al comienzo, así calculamos la posición del primer
// caracter distinto de espacio de la frase.
int initPos = 0;
while(frase[initPos] == ' ') initPos++;
// Recorremos la frase desde la posición calculada
for(int i=initPos; i<100; i++) {
   // Si no hay dos espacios seguidos entonces el carácter
   // actual es parte del texto resultado
   if(!(frase[i]==' ' and frase[i-1]==' '))
   {
      frase[n] = frase[i]; n++;
   }
}

cout<<"\n"<<frase;
```

Observa que con un único bucle es posible hacerlo. El truco está en que no pregunto por el carácter siguiente, sino por el anterior. Primero calculamos la posición del primer carácter para contemplar el caso que la frase comience con espacios y esa posición será el inicio de nuestro bucle. Al preguntar por el anterior me permite aceptar o descartar el carácter actual en el recorrido. Si es un espacio y el anterior lo era también, lo descarto; en otro caso lo acepto y añado en la cadena. La variable *n*, me determina la posición de los caracteres que voy aceptando como solución a lo que se pretende.

Comment: `n` no debería valer inicialmente 0? Prueba con una frase que empiece con varios espacios

Comment: Correcto, no se ha contemplado el hecho que la frase comience con espacios. Modifico la respuesta para tomar en consideración ese caso también.

Comment: Me sirvió bastante lo de preguntar por el carácter anterior, no se me había ocurrido. Pero tengo una duda sobre tu código. En el if pusiste un "!", para que es eso? Probé el código sacándoselo y funciono igual.

Comment: Es el operador de negación. Ahí digo que si no se cumple lo que hay entre paréntesis (es decir que el carácter actual sea espacio y el anterior también) pues entonces ejecuta el código dentro del if en el que aceptamos el carácter actual como parte de la solución.

Answer (score 2):

Hice esta usando la clase `string` de c++ en caso de que quisieras explorar otro camino (y entendiendo que tal vez seas principiante), es meramente para propósitos didácticos y como reto personal:

```
for (size_t index = myStr.find("  "); index!=string::npos; index=myStr.find("  ")){
    myStr.erase(index,1);
}
```

Funciona buscando la string `"  "` y cuando la encuentra le borra el primer espacio, el ciclo `for` deja de ejecutarse cuando ya no encuentra espacios dobles. Me gusta porque es solo un `for` con una sola instrucción.

```
string myStr;
cout<<"Ingrese frase: "; 
getline(cin, myStr); 
for (size_t index = myStr.find("  "); index!=string::npos; index=myStr.find("  ")){
    myStr.erase(index,1);
}
cout<<"\n"<<myStr;
```

Comment: Usando la clase `string` no sería necesario hacer la inicialización de 100 caracteres, de eso se encargará `getline`

Comment: :0 muchas gracias @eferion. Ya la edito!